# How to know why file isn't transferring?

Tags: ios, watchos-2, watchconnectivity

I'm transferring a file from iOS to WatchOS. applicationContext and userInfo transfers all work fine.  When I run the following code, nothing is transferred. fileTransfer.transferred == false.

```
let fileTransfer = WCSession.defaultSession().transferFile(fileurl, metadata: dict)
```

I can see all of my attempts queued up when I look at:

```
let transfers = WCSession.defaultSession().outstandingFileTransfers
```

Is there something I can check that will provide feedback as to why nothing is getting transferred?  I'm using simulators.  The file is a plist file.  I'm accessing it like this:

```
let fileurl = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("myfile", ofType: "plist")!)
```

`fileurl` does return the file path.

Comment: what version of iOS and watchOS are you running?